# What other factors can affect the appearance of a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I made my first WPF app and brought it to work to use. My work computer's monitor is a maximum of 1680 x 1050, 96 dpi, Win 7 system, whereas my home computer is 1920 x 1080p, 96 dpi, Win 7.

The app doesn't display correctly on the work computer. Text is cluttered and 'doesn't fit' where it should, etc (the problem seems to be with the font sizing, only). I'm reading that I did just about everything wrong in regards to making the app support multiple resolutions, so I certainly have some reworking to do.

The odd thing is the work computer appears incorrectly at all lower resolutions, whereas my home computer appears correctly at all lower resolutions, including 1680 x 1050 - meaning I can't duplicate the problem on the computer I am working on the app on.

Here is the font I am using since that seems to be where the problem may lie:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Linux Libertine G"/>
```

What other factors could be affecting the appearance of my app besides resolution?

Comment: I don't know dude. Post some relevant XAML and some screenshots of OK versus bad.

Comment: Did you embed the font, "Linux Libertine G" in the app (or is it available on your work computer)?

Comment: I copied the contents of the bin/debug folder, the other computer has the same .NET framework installed. The font comes with VS2012 - is it possible the other computer wouldn't have the font? If memory serves, the font appeared to be the correct font - just too big

Comment: @svenoaks - that font does not ship with Visual Studio 2012. You must have installed it from somewhere else. Unless you embed the font (check license), copying the bin/debug folder won't help. You're likely seeing a font substitution. It's very likely the other computer doesn't have that font.

Comment: thanks that's probably it then